# Azure SQLへBEGIN TRANSACTIONによりDoCmd.TransferDatabase でExportするとtimeoutする

Tags: sql, sql-azure, vba

以下AccessのVBAで
Azure SQLへBEGIN TRANSACTIONによりDoCmd.TransferDatabase でExportするとtimeoutしてしまいます。
BEGIN TRANSACTIONを外すと正常にExportできるのですが、事情により使用しなければならず、BEGIN TRANSACTIONを使用したExport方法をご存知の方、サポート、よろしく願いします。

```
Set db = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

db.ConnectionTimeout = 0
db.Open "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=tcp:***.database.windows.net,1433;Database=****;Uid=*****;Pwd={****};Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=3000;QueryTimeout=3000;"

Dim Mydb As Database
Set Mydb = CurrentDb
Mydb.QueryTimeout = 0
db.CommandTimeout = 0

cmd.ActiveConnection = db
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

db.Execute "BEGIN TRANSACTION"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC データベース", "ODBC;DSN=****;UID=****;PWD=****;", acTable, "TMP_aaa", "aaa", False, True
```

解決方法ご存知の方、よろしく願いします。

Comment: コード部分を整形し見やすくしました。あとsql-azureのタグを追加しました。

Comment: tomuteさん 
整形ありがとうございます。 
 
db.Execute "BEGIN TRANSACTION" 
を削除すると正常にExportできました。

Comment: 解決出来て何よりです。解決策を回答として投稿し、チェックマークを付けておいて頂けると、本質問が解決していることが他のユーザーに分かりやすくなりますので、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: tomuteさん アドバイスありがとうございます。ただ、サーバーへのExportは事前にサーバー側のテーブルを削除しなければならず、途中でエラーとなった場合、テーブル自体が存在しなくなるのを防ぐ意味で"BEGIN TRANSACTION"を使用しなければなりません。"BEGIN TRANSACTION"を使用してExportする方法がわかればよいのですが、、ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらサポートよろしく願いします。

Comment: では「BEGIN TRANSACTIONを使用してExportする方法が知りたい」という情報を質問に追記しておいてもらうと、回答者の参考になると思います。